# PDF size in a UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I just want to know if it's possible to know the size of a pdf after loading it in a UIWebView ?
When we use a code like this :

```
[self.siteWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.fr/test.pdf"]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is absolutely possible to get height of pdf (1 page height or anything) in uiwebview. I have done before. Below code show how to get 1 page height in uiwebview.

```
-(void)getPDFInfo    
{
NSURL* pdfFileUrl = self.fileLocation;


CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);
CGPDFPageRef page;

// CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200); // thumbnail size


NSUInteger totalNum = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
numberOfPage= totalNum;
for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
    CGPDFPageRef myPageRef=CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i+1);
    //aRect=CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);

    CGRect cropBox = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
    pdfWidth= cropBox.size.width;
    pdfHeight=cropBox.size.height;

    NSLog(@"cropbox size is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(cropBox));

    int pageRotation = CGPDFPageGetRotationAngle(myPageRef);

    CGSize pageVisibleSize = CGSizeMake(cropBox.size.width, cropBox.size.height);
    if ((pageRotation == 90) || (pageRotation == 270) ||(pageRotation == -90)) {
        pageVisibleSize = CGSizeMake(cropBox.size.height, cropBox.size.width);
    }



}
}
```

After you call this function, call this line to get your pdf file size in uiwebview.

```
documentHeightInWebview = pdfHeight * (documentWidthInWebview/pdfWidth);
```

where documentWidthInWebview is your real uiwebview width which will show your pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to get information. put it in webview did load. For example, the following will get the height of the page.

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

//get the height of the chunk, and store it.
CGFloat height = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height;"] floatValue];
```

Comment: are you calling the string by evaluating after the web view has completed loading. It will be 0 until there is content. I have never tried it with just a pdf though.

Comment: I execute this code in the webViewDidFinishLoad method so I think the web view is completel loaded, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes it should be by that stage. I'm not 100% sure how you can do it though. The only other suggestion i have is to download the pdf to the device, store it locally, use the core graphics methods to get the height of the document (get first page, get page height, etc), and then display the local pdf in your web view.